# detect language with javascript and redirect to another page

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I need that when a user opens my website, he detects the language and redirects it to the language of the browser. I'm trying this but it goes into a loop and the page is constantly loaded. I hope you can help.

```
window.onload = function() {

  var ln = window.navigator.language||navigator.browserLanguage;

  if(ln == 'en'){

    window.location.href = 'index_en.html';

  }else if(ln == 'es'){

    window.location.href = 'index_es.html'; 

  }else{

    window.location.href = 'index_es.html'; 

  }

}
```

Comment: I assume you'll want to redirect *only* if the loaded version is different than `ln`...

Comment: You could use a cookie to track the assumed language. If it's unset, then do what you're doing but first set the cookie. If it's set, then just see if it's the same as the detected language and if so no reload is necessary.

Comment: Only put the code in `index.html` and *not* in `index_en.html` etc?

Comment: If I speak spanish and **manually** elect to load the `_es` page, I wouldn't want it redirecting to `_en`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set a cookie before the redirect. Then on the next reload the cookie will have a value and you can stop the script using 'return'

```
window.onload = function() {

    var ln = window.navigator.language||navigator.browserLanguage;
    var myApp = {}

    /**
     * Gets cookie value by name
     * @param  {string} name Name of cookie to retrieve
     * @return {string}      Value of cookie if found
     */
    myApp.ReadCookie = function(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return null;
    };

    /**
    * Removes cookie value
    * @param  {string} name Name of cookie
    */
    myApp.EraseCookie = function(name) {
        if ( myApp.ReadCookie(name) )
        document.cookie = name+'=';
        console.log(name+' erased.');
    };

    /**
    * Deletes cookie reference
    * @param  {string} name Name of cookie
    */
    myApp.DeleteCookie = function(name) {
        document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        console.log(name+' deleted.');
    };

    /**
    * Set cookie value
    * @param  {string} name Name of cookie
    */
    myApp.SetCookie = function(name, value, expires) {

        var cookiestring = [[name, '=', encodeURIComponent( value )].join('')];
        var expire_time = '';

        if ( expires ) {
            expire_time = new Date();
            expire_time.setTime( expire_time.getTime() + expires );
            expire_time = expire_time.toGMTString();
            cookiestring.push( ['expires=', expire_time ].join('') );
        }
        cookiestring = cookiestring.join(';')+';';
        document.cookie = cookiestring;
        console.log( 'SetCookie: '+ name +' set to "'+ value +'"', 'Expires?', expire_time );
    };

    if(myApp.ReadCookie('lang_redirect')) {
        return;
    }

    myApp.SetCookie('lang_redirect', ln);

    if(ln == 'en'){
        window.location.href = 'index_en.html';
    }else if(ln == 'es'){
        window.location.href = 'index_es.html'; 
    } else{
        window.location.href = 'index_es.html'; 
    }

}
```